# Selenium-webdriver.wait(): what gets returned?

Tags: javascript, web-testing, selenium-server

Running a Mocha test, using Selenium-Webdriver, I have

```
driver.get(destinationPage);
driver.wait(function() {
  return driver.isElementPresent(By.xpath(xpathLocation));
}, 3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLocation))
      .sendkeys('87654321');
done();
```

But, I am getting the error `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sendkeys'`

Why would that be? What (if anything) is returned by wait()?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this work if you take out the wait line? or put the wait line as the last line?

Comment: The question is, what is `driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLocation))` returning. Because that is what is causing the error.

Comment: Correct: when I pass findElement an xpath location (found using FirePath) to a text input, I don't expect an error telling me that object has no sendkeys method. I can only conclude that findElement is returning something other than a form input object. 
Not working on this, today. But, when I can get back to it, I'll try just capturing whatever findElement returns and check to see if it is undefined, null or something else entirely...